# CORS via accessing Amazon S3 via Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I have gone through all solutions mentioned in stackoverflow but yet I am not able to solve the error .I am receiving 403 Error while listing all my buckets in S3 and also getting the same error while listing objects in a particular bucket .

I have changed my CORS config on S3 as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

But to no vain .My code is like below

```
s3=new  AWS.S3({ accessKeyId: userId ,secretAccessKey: password, sslEnabled: false, s3ForcePathStyle: true});
    function listBuckets(){
        $("#function").empty();
        $("#function").hide();
        $("#listObjectsOption").hide();
        $("#uploadFile").hide();
        s3.listBuckets(function(err,data){
      console.log(data);
    }
```

The Browser which I am using is Google Chrome.

Can anyone please suggest. Error Which I am getting is

```
aws.js:8167 OPTIONS 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://s3.amazonaws.com/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

Also I am not able to create Bucket or take any actions.

Answer (score -1):

Probably has nothing to do with CORS because you are using the API here. The user whos access/secret keys you use probably doesnt have the necessary permissions. listBuckets needs a policy like this:

```
{
        "Sid": "Stmt1472023667000",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
}
```

Comment: well adding ListAllMyBuckets says invalid action

Comment: in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-configuring.html under "Configuring CORS for an Amazon S3 Bucket" it says "Note that this does not authorize the user to perform any actions on the bucket, it simply enables the browser's security model to allow a request to S3. Actual permissions for the user must be configured either via bucket permissions, or IAM role level permissions.". Are those IAM role level permissions set?

Comment: Policy has invalid action - s3:ListAllMyBuckets for IAM policy
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1475046496223",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::sample/*",
"Principal" : { "AWS" : "*" }
    }
  ]
}

Comment: where is that error from? For ListAllMyBuckets you dont specify bucketname. It complains about principal for me. Should look like {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::sample/*"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}